# Xamarin IOS-Firebase pushnotification not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Firebase push notification is not working for xamarinforms iOS, it is working in xamarin android. I have followed all the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin)
in the document, but push notification is not working.

On searching some one said to enable push notification in entitlements if latest xcode is installed. On enabling push notification in entitlements i am getting another error **Application could not be uploaded to device**

> ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.x95ODI/extracted/Payload/Demo.iOS.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
>   error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/user/Desktop/Demo - Copy 2/Demo/Demo.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone7.2-10.3.2/Demo.iOS.app' on the device 'Focaloid's iPhone 6': Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).

Is there any way to fix this issue.

Comment: "Application could not be uploaded to device" this happens in simulator or device? happen after xcode update?

Comment: Happening in device

Comment: error is not related to firebase plugin. read this carefully "Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured"

Comment: check this documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html

Comment: this happens only when giving push notification in entitlement. What i have to do in certificate to fix this.

Comment: Check 3rd image of the link i shared, then you will understand

Comment: push notification is enabled in certificate

Comment: GOTO  Targets -> Capabilities and verify Push Notifications is all correct

Comment: after update sometimes it can be disabled

Comment: I am using xamarin studio. Yes push notification is enabled here

Comment: you have to check on Capabilities on xcode, xcode default is pushnotificaion disabled and sometimes when you update it become disabled

Comment: Hi, we cant open xamarin project in xcode.

Comment: Xcode 8 does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1."

Comment: nothing is working. i did every steps